# Resize partition using Gparted

Tags: partitioning, gparted, format, lock

I want to resize my primary partition using Gparted, but due to the lock I am not able to do so:

[image: Partitions in gparted]

I would be grateful if someone tells me how to get rid of the lock so that I can resize this partition.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/217571/cant-format-delete-locked-partition-from-gparted

Comment: You need to boot into ubuntu-live cd and do this. [You are trying to do this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/dAynZ.jpg)

Comment: what do you mean by "boot into ubuntu-live cd" ?

Comment: For creating a Ubuntu livecd/liveusb, please see this topic: http://askubuntu.com/questions/26269/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-from-an-usb-drive-create-a-live-usb-stick-in-windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why it does not work is that the `sda1` partition is 'mounted'. It is accessed  by some software and kept in RAM memory for various reasons. It's just like in Windows when some file is being blocked from deletion while accessed/opened by some software. You need to 'unmount' that partition in order to edit it in GParted.

This cannot be done from within a running system, you will have to (create and) use a GParted or Ubuntu LiveCD/LiveDVD/LiveUSB. Insert the live medium into PC and boot to the desktop. At this point, all partitions on the internal disk should be unmounted, thus unlocked. Open GParted and edit them as you desire.

Note : When doing it from an Ubuntu Live media, right-click the swap partition - select `swapoff`.