# Helping to extend Ubuntu size

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive

I started looking at Ubuntu and after a while, I realized that for a long time I haven't log on Windows, so I decided to use Ubuntu as my main OS, I shrink the Window Partition, but I cannot seem to be able to create or extend my Ubuntu Partition size, the following is a screenshot of my HD distribution.

[image]

Any help? thanks in advance

Comment: There are a number of possible solutions to this issue mentioned here: [can't format / delete locked partition from gparted?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/217571/cant-format-delete-locked-partition-from-gparted)

Comment: I cannot seem able either to swap off or even resize.

Comment: nada, always giving the error:  'Cannot create or modify partition'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned, there are a number of ways to do this.

First, I hope that you resized your Windows partition using Windows built-in Disk Management app, not gparted. If you DID use gparted, please boot into Windows RIGHT NOW and assure that you haven't caused any problems there.

Second, **BACKUP** all your important data on sda7 (/home).

Third, boot to the Ubuntu Live DVD in "Try Ubuntu" mode, and start **gparted**. In **gparted**, first issue a **swapoff** command, found in the menus. No partitions should have a gold padlock next to the partition name. All of the remaining steps in gparted should be done ONE AT A TIME. Don't stack commands.

Note, please understand that you can delete/move/resize partitions. I **move** partitions left/right by **dragging** the entire partition. I **resize** by dragging the **right** handle of the partition.

Next we have to **move** the entire extended partition sda3 all the way left. This will bring along the contained partitions sda6/7/8/5. *(This particular move may have to be done by changing the numerical space BEFORE the start of the partition to zero)*.

Then we have to **resize** the extended partition sda3 by either 1) dragging its rightmost handle all the way to the right, or 2) numerically setting the space AFTER the partition to zero.

Then we **move** sda5 first, and then sda8 partitions, all the way to the right.

Then we **resize** sda7 (/home) to increase it by, say, ~+80GB *(adjust to your own requirements)*. Then **move** sda7 all the way right.

Then we **resize** sda6 (/) maximum to the right. This will increase the size to ~+30GB.

Go back to the menus and issue a **swapon** command.

Done.

Let me know if you have any questions. Cheers, Al

Answer (score 2):

You cannot modify the size of a partition which is currently mounted.

---

**You will need:**

An Ubuntu installation DVD, CD, or USB device.

---

What you must do is log off and power down Ubuntu completely, do not hibernate.

**First:**

use an Ubuntu installation disk or USB to boot up and run a "live session".

**Next:**

Open gparted with permission or use the command: `sudo gparted` to open gparted.

**Finally:**

You should now be able to modify the size of these partitions.