# Encountered problem resizing LVM drive with GParted

Tags: 14.04, mount, virtualbox, gparted, lvm

I've been running a virtual version of Ubuntu via Virtualbox on Windows 8 (host) for a while. However it's recently started to run low on space so I've been using this tutorial to resize it:
http://derekmolloy.ie/resize-a-virtualbox-disk/#prettyPhoto

I've got as far as "step 3" (although in reality there are a lot more steps.... I've actually got to the stages around Fig3/Fig4 in that section) but I've encountered a problem.

[Gparted shows my /dev/sda2 and /dev/sda5 as being locked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJ0Qh.png)

I read in [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217571/cant-format-delete-locked-partition-from-gparted/218732#218732?newreg=f56c6860c18e43088bc7643e7fb0a604) about running `lvremove`, `lvscan`, etc, but when I try to do that I get the following error message:

```
user@debian:~$ lvscan
Warning: Running as a non-root user. Functionality may be unavailable.
/run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed: Permission denied
Warining: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to internal scanning.
user:debian:~$
```

Normally I'd be happy to fiddle with things until I can work it out, but due to what could happen if I mess this up I'm reluctant to blindly fiddle in this instance. I have had a google but haven't been able to find out what I need to do to get past this.

Can someone please advise either:

1. what I need to do to be able to run this as a non-root user,
2. what I need to do to be able to run this as a root user 
   (It's a fresh Gparted CD running on a fresh VirtualBox Ubuntu setup
   so I haven't setup any users on it yet)
3. anything else I need to do to get this to run, so I can continue with the above tutorial.

Please note: I'm a front end web developer primarily used to work in a windows environment, so if you can keep any instructions simple and assume no assumed linux/Gparted knowledge that would be much appreciated :-)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to grow the LVM2 PV partition, you will first need to **deactivate** LVM.  After that you can grow the extended partition followed by the LVM2 PV partition.  The steps roughly are as follows:

1. **Backup your data** in case anything should happen to go wrong.
2. Boot VM using GParted Live.
3. Select /dev/sda5 LVM2 PV partition
4. Choose **Partition -> Deactivate**
5. Select /dev/sda2 Extended partition
6. Choose **Partition -> Resize/Move**
7. Grow the partition to the end of the drive.
8. Select /dev/sda5 LVM2 PV partition
9. Choose **Partition -> Resize/Move**
10. Grow the partition to butt up against the end of the sda2 Extended partition.
11. Apply the operation
12. Exit GParted, and boot into the VM OS.
13. In a terminal window, with root privilege (**su** or **sudo**), use the appropriate **lvresize** command line options to grow the logical volume(s) you wish to increase in size.

'Hope that helps.

Comment: Fantastic, that was surprisingly easy/simple :-) Thank you!

Comment: (FYI - I've upvoted the answer but it's not showing as (as I'm a new user) I have a rep of <15 at the mo so it wont let me)

Comment: RE:  upvote not showing.  No worries Kessa.  The important thing is that you were able to accomplish your goal.  :-)