# I am getting an error while trying to resize my ubuntu lvm partition,through live cd

Tags: partitioning, gparted, lvm, resize

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/esgN8.png)    GParted 0.25.0 --enable-libparted-dmraid --enable-online-resize

```
Libparted 3.2
Shrink /dev/sda3 from 930.54 GiB to 929.33 GiB  00:00:00    ( ERROR )

calibrate /dev/sda3  00:00:00    ( SUCCESS )

path: /dev/sda3 (partition)
start: 2050048
end: 1953523711
size: 1951473664 (930.54 GiB)
shrink file system  00:00:00    ( ERROR )

lvm pvresize -v --setphysicalvolumesize 974475264K /dev/sda3  00:00:00    ( ERROR )

0 physical volume(s) resized / 1 physical volume(s) not resized
Using physical volume(s) on command line.
Archiving volume group "ubuntu-vg" metadata (seqno 9).
/dev/sda3: Pretending size is 1948950528 not 1951473664 sectors.
Resizing volume "/dev/sda3" to 1948950528 sectors.
Resizing physical volume /dev/sda3 from 0 to 237908 extents.
/dev/sda3: cannot resize to 237908 extents as later ones are allocated.

========================================
```

Comment: Are you trying to decrease the size of your lvm volume? Or your sda3 partition? Or both? Does the lvm partition take up the entire sda3 partition? You should probably use ubuntu-vg (or maybe /dev/mapper/ubuntu-vg, or something like that) instead of /dev/sda3 (which is the physical partition). Maybe add a gparted screenshot to your question. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/196125/how-can-i-resize-an-lvm-partition-i-e-physical-volume

Comment: And https://askubuntu.com/questions/929712/encountered-problem-resizing-lvm-drive-with-gparted

Comment: And https://help.ubuntu.com/search.html?cof=FORID%3A9&cx=003883529982892832976%3Ae2vwumte3fq&ie=UTF-8&q=resize+lvm&sa=Search

Comment: I am new to this,I think my sda3 is an lvm type partition ,I have included screenshot

Comment: If you took the screenshot when booted to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB, then you'll need to unmount the partitions first. Note the key icon that shows that they're mounted now. Then review the 3 links that I gave you.