# Unknown disk label when trying to install ubuntu

Tags: partitioning

trying to install ubuntu I get error message that the disk is locked and cannot be formated.  Gparted also is thwarted in trying to remove this partition showing a lock on it. Other programs report that it has an unknown disk label and cannot "report" to the linux kernel.  So at this point it appears the disk drive is essentially bricked?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't format / delete locked partition from GParted?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217571/cant-format-delete-locked-partition-from-gparted)

Comment: Did you dd an ISO to drive, or something similar? That makes label as unknown. Label should be gpt or maybe MBR(msdos).  While for flash drives, may apply to your drive? Reset USB flash that was dd'd to make it usable again, reuse
https://askubuntu.com/questions/939230/formatting-a-usb-stick-unable-to-operate-usb/939266#939266 & 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb#Re-use_the_pendrive  or `sudo parted /dev/sda mklabel gpt` But if drive was MBR, that will totally erase everything and then testdisk maybe better to recovery partitions.